# Getting an image laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I hope someone has used Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart.

I'm using it to create a shopping cart and I've read the documentation but haven't seen anything regarding putting the product image in the checkout page.

I've only managed to get title, qty and price. All I need is the image

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object of the item when adding it to the cart and then you'll be able to retrieve any extra information you might need from each item.